# How to prove this particular set is a countable set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f(x)$ is defined on $[0,1]$, and $\exists M$, s.t. for any finite $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in [0,1]$, we have $|f(x_1)+\cdots+f(x_n)|\le M$. Prove E = $\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)\neq 0\}$ is a countable set.

I've got a simple idea to change to $\cup\{x:|f(x)|\ge \frac{1}{n}\}$, but don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Each of the $\{x : |f(x)| \geq {1 \over n}\}$ has to be a finite set due to Archimedean property of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

if $f(x)\neq0$ then there exists $x_0\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)\neq0$. Using the hypothesis for $x_1=x_2=...=x_n=x_0$ then $n|f(x_0)|<M$ and so $|f(x_0)|<\frac{M}{n}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which means that $|f(x_0)|$ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $n$ large enough. This is impossible.